# can't import analysis_accu from evaluate

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, evaluate

So I have been working on *google colab* and when I try to import `analysis_accu`, it shows this error

```py
from evaluate import analysis_accu
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-f2f312c64934> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 from evaluate import analysis_accu

ImportError: cannot import name 'analysis_accu' from 'evaluate' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/evaluate/__init__.py)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I resolve this error in *google colab* ?

Comment: Are you sure `analysis_accu` is the correct name to import?  Where did you get that name?  Are you working from an example or tutorial?